# I restarted Chrome to upgrade and lost all my tabs & windows. How do I get them back?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I restarted Chrome to upgrade it by clicking Upgrade Chrome and now I lost all my tabs & windows that I had open. How do I get them back? I looked in History and it shows many pages from yesterday but not the tabs I had. I looked in Recent Tabs and it's empty.

Comment: I have experienced Chrome losing its saved session numerous times, once its lost, then there is nothing that can be done.  Which is there reason I use a third-party plugin that handles and records the session itself as an additional backup and

Answer (score -1):

You better to get some help from Google [Chrome help](https://support.google.com/chrome/?hl=en#topic=3227046). This may be a bug, so it will help them to improve chrome.